# RecyclerView Inside RecyclerView With Pagination For Both RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have implementing a recyclerview inside recyclerview with pagination call addOnScrollListner but it didn't triggerd for child recyclerview.

Here's what i implementing :

```
class NSREActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


private var previousTotal = 0
private var loading = true
private val visibleThreshold = 5
private var firstVisibleItem = 0
private var visibleItemCount = 0
private var totalItemCount = 0

private lateinit var mAdapter: RecyclerGenericKAdapter<HashTags>
private var mList: ArrayList<HashTags> = ArrayList()
private var mChildList: ArrayList<HashTags> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nsre)

    initData()

    //Usage of generic recycler view
    mAdapter = RecyclerGenericKAdapter(mList, R.layout.item_layout, object : RecyclerKallback<HashTags> {
        override fun bindData(model: HashTags, position: Int, itemView: View) {

            val name = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mainName)
            val childRv = itemView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.childRecycler)

             name.text = model.tag

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@NSREActivity, model.tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                setChildAdapter(childRv)

            }
        }
    })

    recyclerMain.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerMain.adapter = mAdapter

}

private fun setChildAdapter(child : RecyclerView){

    val adt = RecyclerGenericKAdapter(mChildList, R.layout.item_sample_rv, object : RecyclerKallback<HashTags> {
        override fun bindData(model: HashTags, position: Int, itemView: View) {

            val name = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
            name.text = model.tag

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@NSREActivity, model.tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    })

    val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    child.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
    child.adapter = adt

    child.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            visibleItemCount = child.childCount
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.itemCount
            firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

            if (loading) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    loading = false
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount
                }
            }
            if (!loading && totalItemCount - visibleItemCount <= firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold) {
                // End has been reached

                Log.e("Yaeye!", "end called")

                // Do something
                addData()

                loading = true
            }
        }
    })

}

}
```

I have implementing a recyclerview inside recyclerview with pagination call addOnScrollListner but it didn't triggerd for child recyclerview.
when it reached last index of main recyclerview then it will call addOnScrollListner for child recyclerview.

How to call recyclerview inside recyclerview with pagination?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's a proper way, but I had similar problem and I managed to solve it in this way:

I didn't check scroll, but I was checking when last item is binded:

```
class PaginationAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.Holder> {

    var lastItemCreatedHandler: (() -> Unit)? = null

    ...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.Holder, position: Int) {
        if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
            lastItemCreatedHandler?.invoke()
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

And then if there should be more item I show progress, download more data and so on.